# Tips to boost performance of TileLayout?

Tags: android, apache-flex, virtualization, flash-builder4.5

I am targeting mobile using FlashBuilder, I am using `TileLayout` to view items of data, I am setting `useVirtualLayout` to "true"
I have some questions please:

1. Is item renderer resued by default? or shall I set it to true my self?
2. How can I control the range of items being virtualized?
3. Is there any tips on boosting performance of building child items of `TileLayout` ?

If native `TileLayout` is slow, is there alternative control to use? if building my own would be better, is there any example to build custom layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is set to true by default. There are a few instances where they are not virtualized, however. If you have the list sizing to fit its contents, I don't believe virtualization occurs. If I am not mistaken, virtualization only occurs when an `ItemRenderer` leaves the `viewport` of the parent `List` control. So if you have a list on a page and that page is controlling the scrolling and not the list, I don't believe virutalization occurs. That is what I have seen in the past. Not sure if that is how it actually works, but that is the impression I have gotten. Easy way to find out is to throw a trace statement in your `DataChange` handler. If it traces out after initialization, you know virtualization is working
2. I'm not sure you can control this. You may be able to write a custom layout that does it, but that is likely more trouble than it is worth
3. The `TileLayout` itself is likely not the issue you are having, it is the `ItemRenderer`.

   - On mobile, do not extend any `ItemRenderer` class except `LabelItemRenderer` and `IconItemRenderer`.
   - **Do not** write a renderer in MXML. Write in AS3.
   - Utilize the proper renderer life-cycle. This means you should do very little in your constructor. Maybe set a few properties, but **do not** instantiate any `DisplayObject`. Instead, override `createChildren()` and do it there. Override `layoutContents()` for positioning and sizing. Override `drawBackground()` for handling the background. I highly suggest reading this post from Flextras (you'll see him going by Reboog77 on SO) about writing mobile item renderers. https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex
   - Keep the renderers as simple as possible. If you can get away with drawing directly into the object using the `Graphics` class, do that instead of using a `Rect` or similar.
   - Text is slow to render. Do not change it often and keep the text seen in the renderer to a minimum
   - Use `ContentCache` for any images outside of the `iconDisplay` in `IconItemRenderer`. ContentCache will negate the need for reloading images every single time.(`iconDisplay`/`icon` already utilizes this by default)

Comment: I like this comment.  It is very informative on how to operate in the mobile environment.

Comment: Thanks for informative answer, but what about reusing the same instantiated ItemRenderers? wouldn't this save time instantiate new ItemRenderers again& again? is reusing ( recycling ) ItemRenderers supported too?

Comment: @simo That is the **default** behavior of an `ItemRenderer`. That's the entire purpose of their existence. There is a property called `useVirtualLayout` on all classes that extend `LayoutBase`. If that is set to true, as it is by default, ItemRenderers are reused, except where noted in #1 in my answer. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/supportClasses/LayoutBase.html#useVirtualLayout

Comment: Yea, I forget to test with DataChange, yes the evens is triggered .. slowness is strange as no new itemRenderer is created, I think I will build my own layout .. its hard to build the itemRenderer in AS3, as we are working with designers .. any advice?

Comment: @simo You **must** build it in AS3. The only mobile-optimized renderers are `LabelItemRenderer` and `IconItemRenderer` and those **cannot** be written in MXML.

Comment: For the record, the layouts themselves are already optimized fairly well. Unless you need a layout that has not been created already, you are better off using one of the ones included in the SDK. Again, your problem **is not** the layout itself, but the renderer. Instantiation is not the only place an item renderer can be slow, especially on mobile.

Comment: @simo As one more tip, make sure you are at least using `direct` render mode. You **will for sure** notice low framerates in `cpu` render mode (the default)

Comment: But, as I understand, direct mode is handy when I target Stage3D, right? how can I benefit from it in my layout? I am not using any framework other than Flex

Comment: @simo In my experience, the difference between CPU and Direct (and GPU) is substantial in both vanilla AS3 and Flex projects on mobile.